# How to reset/reload dynamic stepper component using lazy loading angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a dynamic stepper component and I lazy load three modules. There is a parent navigator tab and when is clicked routerlinks to the stepper component and it suppose to load the module of first step CategorylistModule and reset stepper. The problem is that the module is loaded but stepper's step isn't updated. For example, If I click step 2 and then click the navigator I see that the first module CategorylistModule is loaded in the second step and step one doesn't trigger.

```
  (.html)
  <mat-horizontal-stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)" [linear]="false" #stepper >
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index" [routerLink]="['/step' + i]" >
      <div *ngIf="!loadingStep">
          <router-outlet *ngIf="i === selectedStepIndex"></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>


(.routing.ts)

  path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: "search",
    component: StepperComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'step2',
        loadChildren: './grid/grid.module#GridModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'step1',
        loadChildren: './form/form.module#FormModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'step0',
        loadChildren: './categorylist/categorylist.module#CategorylistModule'
      },

(stepper.ts)
    selectionChanged(event: any) {

    this.selectedStepIndex = event.selectedIndex;

    if (event.previouslySelectedIndex > event.selectedIndex) {
    this.loadingStep = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.navigate();
        this.loadingStep = false;
      }, 1000);
    } else {
        this.navigate();
      }
  }
    private navigate(): void {
      this.router.navigate([this.steps[this.selectedStepIndex].title],{relativeTo:this.route});
  }
```